# Hash SHA256 java not the same in PHP

Tags: java, php, spring, hash, sha256

I am trying to solve this issue with my php code.
the original code build in spring security 3.0 framework. and am trying to get the same results in php since am not able to make changes for Java code.

```
public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
             byte[] digested = decode(encodedPassword);
             byte[] salt = EncodingUtils.subArray(digested, 0, 8);
             return matches(digested, digest(rawPassword, salt));
            }
            private byte[] decode(CharSequence encodedPassword) {
             return Hex.decode(encodedPassword);
            }

            Hex.decode:
             public static byte[] decode(CharSequence s) {
              int nChars = s.length();
              if (nChars % 2 != 0) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hex-encoded string must have an even number of characters");
              }

              byte[] result = new byte[nChars / 2];

              for (int i = 0; i < nChars; i += 2) {
               int msb = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16);
               int lsb = Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16);

               if (msb < 0 || lsb < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-hex character in input: " + s);
               }
               result[i / 2] = (byte)((msb << 4) | lsb);
              }
              return result;
             }

            EncodingUtils.subArray:
             public static byte[] subArray(byte[] array, int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
              int length = endIndex - beginIndex;
              byte[] subarray = new byte[length];
              System.arraycopy(array, beginIndex, subarray, 0, length);
              return subarray;
             }

            private byte[] digest(CharSequence rawPassword, byte[] salt) {
             byte[] digest = digester.digest(EncodingUtils.concatenate(salt, secret, Utf8.encode(rawPassword)));
             return EncodingUtils.concatenate(salt, digest);
            }

            public byte[] digest(byte[] value) {
             synchronized(messageDigest) {
              for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
               value = messageDigest.digest(value);
              }
              return value;
             }
            }
```

and for my php code am using

```
function alogs($password, $salt, $algo = 'SHA256', $count = 1024 ,$length = 80)
   {
     $password = strtolower($salt).strtolower($password);
           for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++)
               $password = hash($algo, $password);
                  return $password ? substr($password, 0, $length) : $password;
   }
```

for the password am using : 'cwtcn'
and salt '12345678'
iterations 1024

results in java
encodedPassword:

12345678e5246d4bb776fa6837cbecd5496a0c577c6b1d51a457e4ba68f600787deaad935640e1d2

in php

123456781fdf4f326d05115f5ac31407302aa8cd614f11950e15bd6723b0266bb23812b9

Comment: PHP code has `strtolower`, but Java code doesn't lowercase. --- Java code using UTF-8, PHP code doesn't specify. --- Java iteration loop (why?) feeds raw bytes back in, PHP feeds string of hex digits back in.

Comment: Like @andreas, and one more : the java code loop from 0 to iteration, and php from 1 to iteration